# Metadata of File(mp3) in ListView instead of file path, JavaFX

Tags: javafx

So i have files in my ListView but all of them are displayed as their paths. How can i display title of the song for example, instead of it's full path.

```
 - C:\Users\Aorus\Desktop\Music\music1.mp3
 - C:\Users\Aorus\Desktop\Music\music2.mp3 
 - C:\Users\Aorus\Desktop\Music\music3.mp3
```

Turns into:

```
 - Music1's Title 
 - Music2's Title 
 - Music3's Title
```

How can i achive this?

---EDIT---
I managed to come up with this. This returns file names including the mp3 extension. Any idea how can i now remove that .mp3 at the end?

```
    listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<File>() {
       @Override
       protected void updateItem(File file, boolean empty) {
          super.updateItem(file, empty);
          setText(file == null ? null : file.getName());
       }
    });
```

Comment: you need a custom ListCell.. search for examples of listView.setCellFactory(..) When stuck, come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what's not working as expected :)

Comment: Thanks! I will try it and report back as soon as possible :)

Comment: I added some code as you advised me, is it of any help?

Comment: Maybe you can use `str = str.replace(".mp3", "");`

Comment: I used `setText(file == null ? null : file.getName().substring(0,file.getName().indexOf(".")));` but that worked for me too. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

```
    listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<File>() {
       @Override
       protected void updateItem(File file, boolean empty) {
          super.updateItem(file, empty);
          setText(file == null ? null : 
          file.getName().substring(0,file.getName().indexOf(".")));
       }
    });
```